# Comparing two $_GET values to rows in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to compare two $_GET inputs from a form and add them to an SQL statement if it finds something LIKE that in the database.  Here is the SQL code.

```
<?php
  include('db_connect.php');

  $name1 = $_GET['name1'];
  $name2 = $_GET['name2'];


  $query="SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE `Name` LIKE '$_GET[name1]%' OR '$_GET[name2]%' ";
  $res=mysql_query($query);
  $num=mysql_numrows($res);
  $i=0;

  while($i< $num){
   $Name = mysql_result($res, $i, "Name");
   echo $Name;
   $i++;
  }
?>
```

This works for the first $_GET[name1] field, however I want to return More if name2 matches as well.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is open to SQL-injections. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid injections and hacking attacks.

Comment: Look into PDO and prepared statements. Forgo the cumbersome and tedious manual escaping and the dated mysql_* interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate the strings:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE `Name` LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name1"])."%' OR `Name` LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name2"])."%';";
```

You also need the `LIKE`-operator when you use `OR`.
Maybe it is also a problem that the function `mysql_numrows()` is exactly called `mysql_num_rows()`.

Comment: Ok it looks like it works, but I guess two rows in the database has the same value.  Right now i'm searching by name how else could I do it.  They are apart of teams...

Comment: That's possible if two entries in your mysql-table start with $_GET["name2"]. If you only want one value, you can use `LIMIT 0, 1`.

Comment: How can I further filter that? Each player has an ID can I search on that?  If so how can I tie that to the name?

Comment: I do not know, what exactly you want to do. Is there a maximum user count that should be delivered? Of course you can search for the ID but that does not have to do anything with the names. Is it a user ID or is it an ID of a team?

Comment: It's a user ID.  Each player has it. I want to be able to search by names for example:    Chris Johnson (TEN) but if I do like I did above without the team name, it will return two Chris Johnsons. Is there a way I can attach the PlayerID to the original form when they choose a player name (Using jQuery autocomplete)?

Comment: Ah, alright, but if you search for Chris Johnson, why do you have to name-fields? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: It's because there are two Chris Johnsons in my data.  I think I found the answer.  With jQuery autocomplete I will use the label as the persons name and the value as the PlayerID, so I will be searching with the value not the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your second LIKE needs to reference the correct column:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM Stats 
            WHERE `Name` LIKE '$_GET[name1]%' OR `Name` LIKE '$_GET[name2]%'";
```

Comment: No - you don't get the second value from the database, you get rows matching the second value from the database - and using the query you've provided as amende by nickb you will not get dupicate rows. Go back and look at your data.